# Confidence interval in python given the upper and lower bound array and the average

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, confidence-interval

I have calculated for 250 measurements the average, the upper and lower bound. So I have three arrays with 250 elements. Now I want to generate the confidence interval, I did this in a easy way

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=1.,hspace=1.)

indx = np.argsort(hat_y[:,0])

ysmoothed = gaussian_filter1d(hat_y[indx,0], sigma=2)
plt.plot(ysmoothed, label="average")

uppersmooth = gaussian_filter1d(hat_y[indx,0]+1.96*np.sqrt(var_y[indx,0]*1.0/np.sqrt(B)),2)
plt.plot(uppersmooth, linestyle='-', linewidth=1, label="upper bound")

lowersmooth = gaussian_filter1d(hat_y[indx,0]-1.96*np.sqrt(var_y[indx,0]*1.0/np.sqrt(B)),2)
plt.plot(lowersmooth, linestyle='-', linewidth=1, label="lower bound")
```

Is there a way to take three arrays (average, upper, lower bound) as the input arguments and generate a point plot in python, to show the uncertainty for every measurement?

Similar to the seaborn point plot:
[image]

Comment: You might be interested in https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/fill_between_demo.html or, if you want error bars, https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/errorbar_limits_simple.html.

Comment: Looks like you want an [errorbar](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html)